# Repainting a Swing component produce an awful result

Tags: java, swing, components, repaint, antialiasing

I "drawed" a component to make a kind of knob as I didn't found a way to have a "round JSlider". I use an antialiasing to obtain a good result. When I press the component with my mouse, I modify the cursor postion and I ask to the component to repaint. And then, the problem appears : the result when I repain is awful !

If I ask to repaint only when I release the mouse, it seems the result keeps correct. But that's more complicated to set the knob value if I don't repaint "continuously" the component when I set it.

The "repaint" method that cause the problem is in the run method, at the end of the class.

Does someone already had this problem ? What kind of solution can be used to solve it ?
Here is the code I'm using :

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.RadialGradientPaint;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Knob extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
int length, originX, originY, centerX, centerY, width, height, diameter, squareLength;
int minorTick, majorTick, xTick, yTick, xCursor, yCursor;
int xMouse, yMouse, xMouseOrigin, yMouseOrigin;
float yDeltaMouse;
double angleOrigin, angleRange, angle;
double angleCursorOrigin;
double angleCursorInitial;
Color backgroundColor, knobColor;
boolean mousePressed;
Thread t;

Knob () {
    System.out.println("Knob");
    angleCursorOrigin=0.5;
    angleCursorInitial=0.5;
    knobColor =new Color(0,255,0,255);      
    minorTick=9;
    majorTick=3;

    this.addMouseListener(this);
}

public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    width=this.getWidth()/10*10;
    height=this.getHeight()/10*10;

    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D)g;
    System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings", "on");
    System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true");
    g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    if (width>height) {
        length=height;
    } else {
        length=width;
    }
    centerX=width/2;
    centerY=height/2;

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    squareLength = (int )(length*0.9);
    originX=(width-squareLength)/2;
    originY=(height-squareLength)/2;

    /*
    //-45 = (-(Math.PI)/4)
    angleOrigin= -45;
    // 270 = (3*(Math.PI)/2)
    angleRange=270;
    //g.drawRect(originX, originY, squareLength, squareLength);
    //g.fillArc(originX, originY, squareLength, squareLength, (int)angleOrigin, (int)angleRange);
    for (int i=0; i<minorTick ; i++) {
        angle=((i*angleRange/(minorTick-1))+angleOrigin)-7;
        //System.out.println(angle*360/(2*Math.PI));
        xTick= (int) (centerX+Math.cos(angle)*squareLength/2);
        yTick= (int) (centerY-Math.sin(angle)*squareLength/2);
        //g.drawLine(centerX, centerY, xTick, yTick);
        //g.fillArc(originX, originY, squareLength, squareLength, (int)angle, (int)14);
    }
    */

    angleOrigin=-(Math.PI)/4;
    angleRange=3*(Math.PI)/2;       
    g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(length/50+1));        
    for (int i=0; i<minorTick ; i++) {
        angle=i*angleRange/(minorTick-1)+angleOrigin;
        //System.out.println(angle*360/(2*Math.PI));
        xTick= (int) (centerX+Math.cos(angle)*squareLength/2);
        yTick= (int) (centerY-Math.sin(angle)*squareLength/2);
        //g.drawLine(centerX, centerY, xTick, yTick);
        g2D.draw (new Line2D.Float(centerX, centerY, xTick, yTick));
    }

    backgroundColor = this.getBackground();
    g.setColor(backgroundColor);
    diameter=(int)(length*0.8);
    originX=(width-diameter)/2;
    originY=(height-diameter)/2;
    g.fillOval(originX, originY, diameter, diameter);


    /*
    RadialGradientPaint gp;
    Point2D center= new Point2D.Float(width/2, height/2);
    diameter=(int)(length*0.75);
    originX=(width-diameter)/2;
    originY=(height-diameter)/2;
    float radius=diameter/2;        
    float[] dist = {0.7f, 1f};
    Color[] colors = {Color.BLUE, Color.GRAY};
    gp=new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius, dist, colors);
    g2D.setPaint(gp);       
    g2D.fillOval(originX,originY,diameter,diameter);
    */
    diameter=(int)(length*0.75);
    originX=(width-diameter)/2;
    originY=(height-diameter)/2;
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.fillOval(originX,originY,diameter,diameter);

    diameter=(int)(length*0.6);
    originX=(width-diameter)/2;
    originY=(height-diameter)/2;
    g.setColor(knobColor);
    g.fillOval(originX,originY,diameter,diameter);

    g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(length/50+3));
    angle=(2*Math.PI)*(0.75-angleCursorOrigin*0.75)+angleOrigin;
    xCursor= (int) (centerX+Math.cos(angle)*length*0.35);
    yCursor= (int) (centerY-Math.sin(angle)*length*0.35);
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g2D.draw (new Line2D.Float(centerX, centerY, xCursor, yCursor));

}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //System.out.println("Bouton : "+arg0.getButton());

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //System.out.println("Bouton : "+arg0.getButton());
    PointerInfo pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point mouseLocation = pointer.getLocation();
    xMouseOrigin = (int) mouseLocation.getX();
    yMouseOrigin = (int) mouseLocation.getY();
    if (arg0.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        mousePressed=true;
        t= new Thread(new TrackPosition());
        t.start();
    } else if (arg0.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
        angleCursorOrigin=angleCursorInitial;
        repaint();
    }       
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mousePressed=false;
    //System.out.println("Mouse released");

    repaint();

}

class TrackPosition implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (mousePressed==true) {
            PointerInfo pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            Point mouseLocation = pointer.getLocation();
            yMouse = (int) mouseLocation.getY();
            yDeltaMouse=(float)(yMouse-yMouseOrigin)/100;
            angleCursorOrigin=angleCursorOrigin+yDeltaMouse;
            yMouseOrigin=yMouse;
            if (angleCursorOrigin >=1) {
                angleCursorOrigin=1;
            } else if (angleCursorOrigin <= 0) {
                angleCursorOrigin=0;
            }
            //This repaint is a problem if I "uncomment" it
            //repaint();
        }

    }

}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(300,90);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(new Knob());
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: Let's start with the fact that your not calling super.paintComponent and the move in to the fact the your "tracking thread" is over kill and isn't required. You could use a MouseMotionListener instead

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the fact that you are not call `super.paintComponent` before performing in custom painting in your `paintComponent` method.

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and 
[Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Then move onto that fact that your "mouse tracking thread" is overkill and actually isn't required.  Instead you should be using a `MouseMotionListener`, see [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details.

This will relieve you of the need to convert between local and screen contexts.